# Prevent access to a method if another thread is calling a different method

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-synchronization

Suppose I have two threads, T1 and T2. I would like to ensure that if T1 is calling method `A1()`, then T2 cannot call method `B1()`. Similarly, if T1 is calling method `A2()`, then T2 should not be able to call method `B2()`.

How might I achieve this?

```
class A { 
    public void A1() {
    }

    public void A2() {
    }
}

class B {
    public void B1() {
    }

    public void B2() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Start to read here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html

Comment: Is it important that only T1 and T2 are blocked from accessing the methods or is it acceptable for all other threads to be blocked? The latter is much easier to achieve using locks.

Comment: Those voting to close as "unclear" would help us all by adding comments to help clarify the question.

Comment: Can you lock on the same object?

Answer (score 0):

You may try it this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ReentrantReadWriteLock ONE = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    final ReentrantReadWriteLock TWO = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

    Runnable t1 = new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            A a = new A();
            ONE.writeLock().lock();
            try { a.A1(); } finally { ONE.writeLock().unlock(); }
            TWO.writeLock().lock();
            try { a.A2(); } finally { TWO.writeLock().unlock(); }
        }
    };

    Runnable t2 = new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            B b = new B();
            ONE.writeLock().lock();
            try { b.B1(); } finally { ONE.writeLock().unlock(); }
            TWO.writeLock().lock();
            try { b.B2(); } finally { TWO.writeLock().unlock(); }
        }
    };
    new Thread(t1).start();
    new Thread(t2).start();
}

class A {
    public void A1() {
        System.out.println("A1");
        try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
    public void A2() {
        System.out.println("A2");
        try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}

class B {
    public void B1() {
        System.out.println("B1");
        try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
    public void B2() {
        System.out.println("B2");
        try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
A1
A2
B1
B2
```

Comment: Worth noting that this prevents all code from accessing `B2()` when `A2()` is in use. This may be fine, but the OP's question is not clear on that subject - there is a suggestion that perhaps only specific threads should be affected by this.

Comment: Yes, you are right. If that is the case, both threads have to share a lock instead.